# onfocus and onblur for only IE7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

Can we write events such as `onblur` or `onfocus` for a specific browser like IE7 ?

What I've tried is below.

```
<asp:TextBox  onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='white'" Text="something" ID="txtName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Note that this is working fine for me. BUT I just need `onblur` and `onfocus` to execute on IE7.

Is that possible?

Perhaps someone has been faced by this need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can detect the browser and run your script only when it is IE7

put it in the end of your markup body tag

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var txtBox = document.getElementById('<%= txtName.ClientID %>');
         txtBox.onfocus =function(){ txtBox.style.backgroundColor='yellow';};
         txtBox.onblur=function(){txtBox.style.backgroundColor='white';};
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

or put this in the head

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload=function(){ 
           var txtBox = document.getElementById('<%= txtName.ClientID %>');
           txtBox.onfocus =function(){ txtBox.style.backgroundColor='yellow';};
           txtBox.onblur=function(){txtBox.style.backgroundColor='white';};
     }
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: it will run only in IE 7! Also, did you put the code in the end of the body??It's working perfectly for me

Comment: I put it in the beginning of <head>. Should I put it there at the end of body?

Comment: when you put it in head, script gets executed before your textbox even appear on the page, hence put it in the body

Comment: if you want to make it work from the head, bind the entire code to the window.load. yeah go ahead

Comment: If you think that is technically fine then I'd leave it there right before the end of `</form>` And my 2nd question/problem is the focus on *multi line* text box is not working in any browser !!! any suggestion ?

Comment: but it is working for me.! same code. actually, textbox multiline is nothing but textarea with rows and cols. and it works

Comment: I know that but for me its not working. Maybe something wrong here in my code, So you mean that CSS:focus works fine with multi line text boxes in all browsers?

Comment: CSS focus? i said javascript event onfocus! yeah it is working for me in chrome, ff, ie 7,8,9

Comment: Well I've done all focus using CSS expect the one you showed me for IE7. So...finally can't that be done using css:focus for multi line text box ?

Comment: OK. Shokrya Manish for giving time and paying attention. Thank you